# Best algorithm to find a repeating pattern

Tags: .net, algorithm, neural-network

What are the best algorithms available to find longest repeating patterns of characters in a string using .net?

Comment: You will have to be more specific. Maybe give some examples. Also, have you done any research yourself already? If so, tell us what you found.

Comment: you can build a dictionary, like what lossless data compression algorithms do. See for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_coder

Comment: your 'edit' does not make it any less vague, IMO.Try to do what Space_C0wb0y suggest.

Comment: I'm unsure why you want the *longest* pattern. Clearly for the string "abcabca" the pattern "abc" is more interesting than "abcabc"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that you speak about *pattern discovery*. Take a look at some elementary aproach ([source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/037047fc-5506-4656-ad27-dab9a6c501ee))

```
private static Dictionary<string, int> FindPatterns(string value) {
  List<string> patternToSearchList = new List<string>();
  for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++) {
    for (int j = 2; j <= value.Length / 2; j++) {
      if (i + j <= value.Length) {
        patternToSearchList.Add(value.Substring(i, j));
      }
    }
  }
  // pattern matching
  Dictionary<string, int> results = new Dictionary<string, int>();
  foreach (string pattern in patternToSearchList) {
    int occurence = Regex.Matches(value, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Count;
    if (occurence > 1) {
      results[pattern] = occurence;
    }
  }

  return results;
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
  Dictionary<string, int> result = FindPatterns("asdxgkeopgkajdflkjbpoijadadafhjkafikeoadkjhadfkjhocihakeo");
  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> res in result.OrderByDescending(r => r.Value)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Pattern:" + res.Key + " occurence:" + res.Value.ToString());
  }
  Console.Read();
}
```

The algorithm consist of 2 stages.

- Choose pattern
- Find pattern in input string (Algorithm of *pattern matching*)

It is used Regex for pattern matching. There are other more advanced algorithms. These algorithms are enlisted on address http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/
However, code samples are written in C. Also you'd take a look on [Boyer-Moore algorithm](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/BoyerMooreSearch.aspx?fid=258714&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=16) for pattern matching, written in C#

Comment: I thinks this is kind of brute force method. Are there algorithms to do this using dynamic programming or some other method ?

Comment: Yes, it's brute force method. I expanded my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode:

```
For N=1 to InputString.Length-1
  rotatedString = RotateStringByN(InputString,N)
  For N=0 to InputString.Length-1
     StringResult[N] = if (rotatedString[N]==InputString[N]) then
                            InputString[N]  
                       else 
                            Convert.ToChar(0x0).ToString()
  RepeatedStrings[] = String.Split(StringResult, Convert.ToChar(0x0).ToString())
  SaveLongestStringFrom(RepeatedStrings)
```

... Or just look here at [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146768/utility-to-find-longest-possible-repeated-strings) for other solutions.